# What is the name of this Font?

Tags: fonts

What is the exact name (and size and other attributes) of this very font Superuser is letting me use to type this very question? And is it open source? And if yes, where can I download it from?

#### Screenshot of font:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the `font-family` CSS attribute for the input box. You can do this by right-clicking the element and choosing *Inspect* or similar menu item. The value is:

> Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif

The browser will use the first font on this list that is present on your system.

`monospace` and `sans-serif` are not font names, but generic placeholders for the default monospace and sans serif font on your system respectively.